# Fix overwritten svn text base etc

Tags: bash, svn, unix

I have a situation where I am using gitHub to manage changes to a repo I pulled from an open source project that uses svn.

Everything has been all well and good until I realised that in using `sed` to change stuff, I have changed the svn tracking files. There are just too many to manually fix.

I basically have [this problem](http://glob.bushi.net.nz/glob/2007/02/14/subversion-checksum-mismatch-easy-workaround/) on a grand scale.

I need these to be intact so I thought I'll do the following:

1. Create a new local working copy of the pristine svn based code.
2. Recursively delete all the non ".svn" folders in this tree. I.E., get to a situation where I have the project tree with only ".svn" folders and their contents in it.
3. Recursively delete all the ".svn" folders in "gitHub" tree.
4. Copy across the ".svn" folder to the "gitHub" tree

Three questions:

- Is this advisable?
- If not, any suggestions on how to recover the svn stuff?
- If on the right track, how do I achieve Step 2? I.E., recursively
  delete everything but the ".svn" folders? I have found a lot ofstuff
  on Google to do Step 3 but this is the flip of those.

Comment: any script that you create, have it just print the command it is going to execute. Then check all of the output. When you're statisfied that all is correct, then you can redirect the script into a shell, i.e. `mySVNfixer | ksh`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that my originally proposed approach has worked just fine.

## Steps Taken

- create 'svnrepos' equivalent of 'gitrepos' to have two sub
  directories to hold actual repo and pristine file set:

`mkdir /home/build/REPOS/svnrepos && mkdir /home/build/REPOS/svnrepos/repos && mkdir /home/build/REPOS/svnrepos/files`

- create local svn repo:

`cd /home/build/REPOS/svnrepos/repos && svnadmin create project_name`

- grab pristine source files. this will untar as 'project_name':

`cd /home/build/REPOS/svnrepos/files && wget http://site.net/project_name.tar.gz && tar -xzf project_name.tar.gz`

- import pristine source files into the new local repo:

`svn import /home/build/REPOS/svnrepos/files/project_name file:///home/build/REPOS/svnrepos/repos/project_name -m "Initial import of project_name"`

- rename existing 'GIT_Project' folder as we will use this name for a
  temporary svn working folder:

`cd /home/build/REPOS/gitrepos && mv GIT_Project GIT_Project_git`

- create new 'GIT_Project' folder and checkout svn repo into this:

`mkdir GIT_Project && svn co file:///home/build/REPOS/svnrepos/repos/project_name /home/build/REPOS/gitrepos/GIT_Project`

- recursively delete every file in the new temporary svn working folder
  that is not under a '.svn' directory tree. Leave folder structure
  intact:

`cd /home/build/REPOS/gitrepos/GIT_Project && find . -type f | grep -v '.svn' | xargs rm -f`

- recursively delete every '.svn' folder in the original git version
  folder:

`cd /home/build/REPOS/gitrepos/GIT_Project_git && rm -rf`find . -type d -name .svn`

- create a tar file from the truncated temporary svn working folder:

`cd /home/build/REPOS/gitrepos && tar -czf svn.tgz GIT_Project`

- remove the temporary svn working folder:

`rm -fr GIT_Project`

- rename the git version folder back to its original name:

`mv GIT_Project_git GIT_Project`

- unpack the truncated temporary svn working folder tar file to add 
  updated '.svn' folders and contents to the git version folder:

`tar -xzkf svn.tgz`

- get the svn status of the git version folder. it will show removed
  files or folders with a '?' prefix and missing files or folders with 
  a '!' prefix. save the list to an external file and use find and
  replace to change these to "svn add" and "svn delete" respectively.
  remember to skip files and    folders that should not be added to
  svn:

`cd GIT_Project && svn status`

- use the amended svn status output to update svn:

`svn add fileORfolder_1 && svn add fileORfolder_2 ... && svn add fileORfolder_n`

`svn delete fileORfolder_1 && svn delete fileORfolder_2 ... && svn delete fileORfolder_n`

`svn commit -m "Realign svn and git"`

Comment: Be careful when parsing the output of `ls`, especially so when looking for filenames/paths.  Files or folders with unexpected characters in them (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc) can cause the script to go haywire.  Using `find` is much safer and more predictable.

Comment: Got it thanks. `ls` works for me here as it skips the `.svn` folders and I know I don't have any funnily named folders. Already tested and verified. The script deletes all files except those under `.svn` trees which is exactly what I want. Backing things up now before going for it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't copy Subversion metadata folders between directories.  It's ***very*** easy to get into trouble doing things that way.

Instead, try creating a script that will revert the changes made to the Subversion metadata.  You can use the command `find . -name .svn -exec some_command '{}' +` to find all Subversion metadata folders and run a command on them.  Replace `some_command` with whatever git command you need to do a recursive revert back to the last known working state.

Another option is to create a branch at the last known working state.  Working from that branch, merge over all of your changes *except* the changes to the metadata folders.  Depending on how long it's been since the metadata was corrupted, this might be an easier approach.

Also note that this is a bit easier if you're using Subversion 1.7, as there will only be a single `.svn` folder per working copy instead of one per directory.  In that case, using `find` may be a bit of overkill.

If you need to delete everything except the "`.svn`" folders, try the command `find $folder -type f | grep -v '.svn' | xargs rm -f`.  That will delete every file in the current directory (recursing into sub-directories) that doesn't have ".svn" in the path.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, I can't go down the suggested route. I have tried copying the metadata for some instances as suggested in my linked page and this appears to work. So any advice on doing the Step 2 will be appreciated.

Comment: @Dayo- Please note that there is a very important difference between "appears to work" and "works".  I have tried things like that in the past and have ended up with serious problems that required me to start over from a fresh checkout.

Comment: @Dayo- I have already given you a command that finds all of the Subversion metadata in a folder tree.  To find everything that's *not* Subversion metadata, invert the condition.  Or, you can simply do a `find . | grep -v '.svn'` (assuming the string "`.svn`" doesn't appear in the path/name of any files in your working copy other than the Subversion metadata).

Comment: I have decided to go down my original path and see what happens for myself. Thanks for the pointers